# RPi2 Fronius serialport converter not mapped to /dev/ttyUSBx

Tags: pi-2, usb, serial

I am using Fronius usb serial conveter (should be standard USB to RS422 converter with FTDI driver I think) but it doesnt connect to any /dev/ttyUSB so I cant use it.
Here are the logs:

```
uname -a: Linux RaspberryPi 4.4.19-v7+ #906 SMP Tue Aug 23 15:53:06 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

dmesg

```
    [    2.027747] Freeing unused kernel memory: 476K (807e9000 - 80860000)                                                     
[    2.123316] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg                                                    
[    2.126342] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101                                                                   
[    2.323664] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514                                                 
[    2.326619] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0                                            
[    2.330573] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found                                                                                   
[    2.333620] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected                                                                                
[    2.613333] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg                                                  
[    2.713814] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00                                               
[    2.716977] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0                                          
[    2.724119] smsc95xx v1.0.4                                                                                              
[    2.789935] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:11:
60:6c                                                                                                                       
[    2.893362] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg                                                  
[    3.024330] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=101e, idProduct=000a                                               
[    3.027821] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3                                          
[    3.031254] usb 1-1.4: Product: Fronius Converter USB                                                                    
[    3.034423] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Fronius                                                                             
[    3.037608] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: A6XEHVTU                                                                            
[    3.075968] udevd[201]: starting version 175                                                                             
[    3.356391] Driver for 1-wire Dallas network protocol.                                                                   
[    3.424611] w1-gpio onewire@0: gpio pin 4, external pullup pin -1, parasitic power 0                                     
[    3.432051] w1_add_master_device: set_pullup requires write_byte or touch_bit, disabling                                 
[    3.513667] bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer                                               
[    3.553503] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000                                       
[    3.584049] bcm2708_i2c 3f804000.i2c: BSC1 Controller at 0x3f804000 (irq 83) (baudrate 100000)                           
[    3.922205] rtc-pcf8563 1-0051: chip found, driver version 0.4.4                                                         
[    3.936258] rtc-pcf8563 1-0051: rtc core: registered rtc-pcf8563 as rtc0                                                 
[    4.958579] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)                                                                
[    6.026100] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)                                                                
[    6.549231] i2c /dev entries driver                                                                                      
[   10.070529] random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read, 94 bits of entropy available)                        
[   10.656065] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                             
[   12.188171] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1                                           
[   16.866533] random: nonblocking pool is initialized                                                                      
[   20.902374] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS                                 
[   23.845184] watchdog watchdog0: Watchdog timer stopped                                                                   
[   35.353421] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                             
[   35.450847] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                             
[   35.477331] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                             
[   35.821141] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                             
[   37.248387] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1                                           
[ 2177.288978] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4                                                                   
[ 2179.318622] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg                                                  
[ 2179.449058] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=101e, idProduct=000a                                               
[ 2179.449087] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3                                          
[ 2179.449104] usb 1-1.4: Product: Fronius Converter USB                                                                    
[ 2179.449120] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Fronius                                                                             
[ 2179.449135] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: A6XEHVTU
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.                                                                
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub                                                              
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.                                                                
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 101e:000a
```

cat /proc/modules

```
binfmt_misc 6388 1 - Live 0x7f09b000                                                                                        
rtc_ds1307 9521 0 - Live 0x7f094000                                                                                         
i2c_dev 5859 0 - Live 0x7f08f000                                                                                            
snd_bcm2835 20447 0 - Live 0x7f085000                                                                                       
snd_pcm 75762 1 snd_bcm2835, Live 0x7f066000                                                                                
snd_timer 19224 1 snd_pcm, Live 0x7f05c000                                                                                  
snd 51908 3 snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm,snd_timer, Live 0x7f045000                                                                  
rtc_pcf8563 6264 0 - Live 0x7f040000                                                                                        
i2c_bcm2708 4770 0 - Live 0x7f03b000                                                                                        
bcm2835_gpiomem 3040 0 - Live 0x7f037000                                                                                    
w1_therm 3584 0 - Live 0x7f033000                                                                                           
spi_bcm2835 6678 0 - Live 0x7f02e000                                                                                        
bcm2835_wdt 3225 1 - Live 0x7f02a000                                                                                        
w1_gpio 3657 0 - Live 0x7f026000                                                                                            
wire 25219 2 w1_therm,w1_gpio, Live 0x7f019000                                                                              
cn 4374 1 wire, Live 0x7f014000                                                                                             
uio_pdrv_genirq 3164 0 - Live 0x7f00c000                                                                                    
uio 8000 1 uio_pdrv_genirq, Live 0x7f000000
```

ls /dev/

```
autofs           gpiomem  loop-control        pts    ram7       stdout  tty2   tty32  tty45  tty58      urandom  vcsa2      
block            hwrng    MAKEDEV             ram0   ram8       tty     tty20  tty33  tty46  tty59      vc-cma   vcsa3      
btrfs-control    i2c-1    mapper              ram1   ram9       tty0    tty21  tty34  tty47  tty6       vchiq    vcsa4      
bus              input    mem                 ram10  random     tty1    tty22  tty35  tty48  tty60      vcio     vcsa5      
cachefiles       kmsg     memory_bandwidth    ram11  raw        tty10   tty23  tty36  tty49  tty61      vc-mem   vcsa6      
char             log      mmcblk0             ram12  root       tty11   tty24  tty37  tty5   tty62      vcs      vcsm       
console          loop0    mmcblk0p1           ram13  rtc0       tty12   tty25  tty38  tty50  tty63      vcs1     vhci       
cpu_dma_latency  loop1    mmcblk0p2           ram14  shm        tty13   tty26  tty39  tty51  tty7       vcs2     watchdog   
cuse             loop2    net                 ram15  snd        tty14   tty27  tty4   tty52  tty8       vcs3     watchdog0  
disk             loop3    network_latency     ram2   sndstat    tty15   tty28  tty40  tty53  tty9       vcs4     xconsole   
fb0              loop4    network_throughput  ram3   spidev0.0  tty16   tty29  tty41  tty54  ttyAMA0    vcs5     zero       
fd               loop5    null                ram4   spidev0.1  tty17   tty3   tty42  tty55  ttyprintk  vcs6                
full             loop6    ppp                 ram5   stderr     tty18   tty30  tty43  tty56  uhid       vcsa                
fuse             loop7    ptmx                ram6   stdin      tty19   tty31  tty44  tty57  uinput     vcsa1
```

I can see that the converter is detected but it is not mapped to /dev/ttyUSB (I have another one which is not from Fronius and it works perfectly but I need to use the one from Fronius.) Also can see that in lsusb the conveter is device 5 but it doesnt have a name, this might be the issue? I tried several times to disconnect the converter and no luck. I tried differetn RPI and no luck.
I also see many /dev/tty (which I actually understand why there is so many) and they disapeary when I connect my other working converter, how this is releated?

Should I write some udev rule? why is this not detected automatically? How the rule should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, basically it is just about registering new device under the unknown (non standard FTDI) vendor ID and product ID
Put this into /etc/rc.local and it works like charm:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial
sudo modprobe ftdi-sio
sudo echo 101e 000a > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```

Maybe loading usbserial is not necessary but I have it there just in case.
I wrote also to Fronius to let them know that they have issue with this converter. Will see if they fix it.
Thanks everyone for help here.
Here are is the source topic I got the idea from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259068